# Symfony Fixture - Reference does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I try to write fixtures in multiple files, I've never created fixtures by setting object, so I try to follow SF doc (https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html#loading-the-fixture-files-in-order)

I have this error: `Reference to "lang49" does not exist` lang49 being first object set

LangFixture:

```
use App\Entity\Lang;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class LangFixture extends Fixture
{
    public const ENGLISH_LANG_REFERENCE = 'lang39';
    public const FRENCH_LANG_REFERENCE = 'lang49';
    public const SPANISH_LANG_REFERENCE = 'lang41';
    public const TURKISH_LANG_REFERENCE = 'lang163';

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
...
        $lang39 = new Lang();
        $lang39->setLang("en");
        $lang39->setName("&#69;&#110;&#103;&#108;&#105;&#115;&#104;");
        $lang39->setEnglishName("English");
        $lang39->setEnabled(true);
        $manager->persist($lang39);
        $this->addReference(self::ENGLISH_LANG_REFERENCE, $lang39);
...
        $lang41 = new Lang();
        $lang41->setLang("es");
        $lang41->setName("&#69;&#115;&#112;&#97;&#241;&#111;&#108;");
        $lang41->setEnglishName("Spanish; Castilian");
        $lang41->setEnabled(true);
        $manager->persist($lang41);
        $this->addReference(self::SPANISH_LANG_REFERENCE, $lang41);
...
        $lang49 = new Lang();
        $lang49->setLang("fr");
        $lang49->setName("&#70;&#114;&#97;&#110;&#231;&#97;&#105;&#115;");
        $lang49->setEnglishName("French");
        $lang49->setEnabled(true);
        $manager->persist($lang49);
        $this->addReference(self::FRENCH_LANG_REFERENCE, $lang49);
...
        $lang163 = new Lang();
        $lang163->setLang("tr");
        $lang163->setName("&#84;&#252;&#114;&#107;&#231;&#101;");
        $lang163->setEnglishName("Turkish");
        $lang163->setEnabled(false);
        $manager->persist($lang163);
        $this->addReference(self::TURKISH_LANG_REFERENCE, $lang163);
...
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

UserFixture:

```
use App\Entity\User;
use App\DataFixtures\LangFixture;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class UserFixture extends Fixture
{
    public const ADMIN_USER_REFERENCE = 'admin';
    public const VISITOR_USER_REFERENCE = 'visitor';
    
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $admin = new User();
        $admin->setLang($this->getReference(LangFixture::FRENCH_LANG_REFERENCE));
        $admin->addLang($this->getReference(LangFixture::FRENCH_LANG_REFERENCE));
        $admin->addLang($this->getReference(LangFixture::ENGLISH_LANG_REFERENCE));
        $admin->addLang($this->getReference(LangFixture::SPANISH_LANG_REFERENCE));
        $admin->setEmail('example1@mail.com');
        $admin->setRoles(["ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"]);
        ...
        $admin->setLangContributor(true);
        $admin->addContributorLang($this->getReference(LangFixture::TURKISH_LANG_REFERENCE));
        $admin->setIsVerified(true);
        $manager->persist($admin);
        $this->addReference(self::ADMIN_USER_REFERENCE, $admin);

        $visitor = new User();
        $visitor->setLang($this->getReference(LangFixture::FRENCH_LANG_REFERENCE));
        $visitor->addLang($this->getReference(LangFixture::FRENCH_LANG_REFERENCE));
        $visitor->setEmail('example2@mail.com');
        $visitor->setRoles(["ROLE_SUPER_VISITOR"]);
        ...
        $admin->setLangContributor(false);
        $visitor->setIsVerified(true);
        $manager->persist($visitor);
        $this->addReference(self::VISITOR_USER_REFERENCE, $visitor);
        
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            LangFixture::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then UserFixture addReferences will be use into MessageFixture...

What's wrong? Thanx

---

UPDATED, now it's ok thanx to exepti0n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using class constants for your languages references, but your are not using them for setting the reference.

```php
$this->addReference('ENGLISH_LANG_REFERENCE', $lang39);
// Results in a reference called "ENGLISH_LANG_REFERENCE"

$this->addReference(self::ENGLISH_LANG_REFERENCE, $lang39);
// Results in a reference called "lang39" since that is the value of your constant
```

Since you are using dependent fixtures your `UserFixture` should implement `DependentFixtureInterface`.

```php
// Old
class UserFixture extends Fixture {

// New
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;

class UserFixture extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface {
```

Comment: Thx for your feedback, yes it is what i done before test this syntax, and i forgot to change back. i have updated my code question... but i do not understand why reference is done unexisted even with self::

Comment: You need the interface, I've updated my answer :)

Comment: I have this error : ```Fixture "App\DataFixtures\LangFixture" was declared as a dependency for fixture "App\DataFixtures\UserFixture", but it was not included in any of the loaded fixture groups.``` I remember had the same error yesterday i tried to fix without success and i didn't found any solution for that, for example a i tried getGroups() etc

Comment: Based on the error I suspect there are other fixtures that are implementing the `Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\FixtureGroupInterface`. Have you tried removing that interface? Unless you really want/need to use groups, then you should add the interface to all fixtures and implement the `getGroups()` method.

Comment: rigth now no fixture use group and i have just remove all dependences from others fixtures just in case. but same error

Comment: Please update your code with the latest version and (full) error message

Comment: Done. I remove all other fixtures to reduce possible error.. I think I've forgot something the first time, (maybe implements DependentFixtureInterface)  and then by dint of testing soluce, I let things drag on to the point of not understanding what was wrong.. I make them from scrath and now it works. Thanw for your help